# distance correlation (distcorr)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have 2 data-frames that I converted to arrays, then ran my code.  I'm not getting any output.  I feel like I'm missing something in the execution output, any thoughts?

```
X = df.to_records(index=False)
Y = df1.to_records(index=False)

def distcorr(X, Y):

    X = np.atleast_1d(X)
    Y = np.atleast_1d(Y)
    if np.prod(X.shape) == len(X):
        X = X[:, None]
    if np.prod(Y.shape) == len(Y):
        Y = Y[:, None]
    X = np.atleast_2d(X)
    Y = np.atleast_2d(Y)
    n = X.shape[0]
    if Y.shape[0] != X.shape[0]:
        raise ValueError('Number of samples must match')
    a = squareform(pdist(X))
    b = squareform(pdist(Y))
    A = a - a.mean(axis=0)[None, :] - a.mean(axis=1)[:, None] + a.mean()
    B = b - b.mean(axis=0)[None, :] - b.mean(axis=1)[:, None] + b.mean()

    dcov2_xy = (A * B).sum()/float(n * n)
    dcov2_xx = (A * A).sum()/float(n * n)
    dcov2_yy = (B * B).sum()/float(n * n)
    dcor = np.sqrt(dcov2_xy)/np.sqrt(np.sqrt(dcov2_xx) * np.sqrt(dcov2_yy))
    return dcor
```

Comment: What do you mean by any output?

Comment: I get no distcorr value...the whole point of the program

Comment: So where does it stop? You must have some error message somewhere?

Comment: this is the output I get:

Comment: [*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 downloaded
[*********************100%***********************]  1 of 1 downloaded
<function distcorr at 0x000000000A47DAE8>

Comment: Obviously you are actually not calling the function, but just returned the function itself.

Comment: yea, sorry about that...when I call it: print (distcorr(X,Y))...i get the ValueError: Number of samples must match

Comment: Great, that's your check, means that it works.

Comment: I see the issue, was using returns vs. price and there was a nan in there